# Datatype for storing video in SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, types

What datatype would be used for storing video files in sql server2000?

Comment: Do you really want to be storing video in a database?

Comment: Cmoon people, answer the question at least, then add a sidenote its not optimal for something. He did not ask for SQL Server 2008 hints or if the video should be in DB, he asked a very straightforward question!

Comment: And we asked a very straight-forward question back. Not everything that is doable should be done, so it is valid to ask the reasons before giving advice.

Comment: Then ask the reason in the comments, don't post it as answer, which it isn't. Post the answer, then say its not really viable. He might even not have a choice how things are designed, he just implements it, we don't know that. Annoys the hell out of me when people think they know everything better..

Comment: I find it odd that you stand guard besides this question, down-voting people accusing them of "knowing everything better" while not giving an answer yourself. You must be knowing the answer, so go ahead and post it.

Comment: I did post my answer, its the first one. If it is not correct, vote it down and post a comment why its wrong. Marc Gravell's answer is the same as mine, so WTF do you whine there?

Comment: Giving an unreflected answer to an unreflected question is... I don'k know. Yes, your answer is technically unimpeachable. You must be right, then, I'm sorry. Besides, your aggressiveness is laughable (even taking into account that I somehow managed to overlook your answer in a set of three).

Comment: @Tuminoid - re SQL 2008 hints: sometimes, knowing what is available in a different version is important as a stimulus to upgrade.

Comment: Sorry, I apologize for the harsh words, that was unwarranted. It just pisses me off when people won't give a straight answer to a simple question, but start to question the motives they have no clue about. We all agree the question is kinda dumb, lets move on. There is an answer and advice posted.

Comment: Okay, apology accepted. My point is this: Asking for advice on a disputable topic, giving no clue on reasoning implies that the question is not well thought-out. Challenging the background is better than bluntly saying "use X", creating the impression that "X" would always be The Right Thing to do.

Comment: This question is a bit like the ever-recurring "Which regex can I use to parse/sanitize this bit of HTML?". Even if the *correct* answer was "use <complicated-regex>", the *right* answer is "Don't use regex, unless you explain why you think you can.". A simple "don't" is not wrong *per se*.

Answer (score 6):

In most cases, a database isn't the ideal place for video. You can force it (varbinary(max), or image on older versions), but if you *do* this, you'll need to be very careful to use steraming access rather than "get all" access (if you see what I mean). And you'd probably want the video on a different file-group (and probably drive) than regular data.

In SQL Server 2008 there is the [filestream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993.aspx) type, which is a hybrid between db and file system. Maybe this will do what you need?

If not, just use the file system.

One other reason not to use video in the DB; if you have a small system, SQL Server Express might be ideal - but has a db size cap that video will quickly swamp.

Comment: SQL SErver EXpress has a 4GB data file limit

Answer (score 5):

Use BLOBs (binary large objects). [Documentation here](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/sql/2000/reskit/part3/c1161.mspx). More specifially:

> In SQL Server, BLOBs can be text, ntext, or image data type
>
> **image**
>
> Variable-length binary data from 0 through 231 - 1 (2,147,483,647) bytes.

Comment: Voting a correct answer to the question down because the way asker is doing things is WRONG, especially without even leaving a comment. There may be a (stupid) requirement why he is doing it, and maybe the files are small (mobile videos for example). Voting down correct answer for it is just STUPID.

Comment: I understand your point but I think giving answers should be about providing the best solution. Storing a BLOB in SQL Server 2000 is not the best solution to storing files IMHO even though as you correctly state; for this specific question it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2000 BLOB support is not good enough and you should definitively store files directly on disk. In SQL Server 2008 support for storing files in the database is supposed to be a lot better. I have never tried it as we had already built our application to store files on disk. But I think I would still recommend to store files on disk as it provides more flexibility in terms of storage; you can easily back it up and move files around. Also it reduces the size of the database which likely will make it faster.

So store the path in your database and the actual files in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Tomalak, even pictures and other smaller assets are much better served outside of the database. Our products use only reference paths to the assets in the DB, with th DB serving as a dictionary to location.

Of course the one down side is the disconnect that can develop between the filesystem and the DB entries, so you need to pay special attention to how you set this up and maintain it in an ongoing fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Save yourself a headache and store them on the file system. Store the path in the DB.

Currently I can't think of a *really* good reason to store videos in a database, when there is a file system available. What are your's?

Comment: I can. It seems like a very cheap way to get replication and integrity services. Educating programmers on how to implement replication and integrity will make it easier for them to see the cost of using SQL for everything...